# Excel : Professional Tax only for maximum value (duty) for repeated names

Tags: excel

I have a data like this,

[image: Excel Data]

I want formula in PT column, I have written desired results in PT column manually.

Formula should first total the amount of wages in various units for that person then check where the person performed maximum duty and Insert professional tax amount in that row. For example, Rohan performed maximum duty in RIL, then his PT should be inserted in the same row, all other rows containing the name Rohan should remain blank.

So far i have calculated the formula to get PT

```
=IFS([@Wages]<6000,"",AND([@Wages]>=6000,[@Wages]<=9000),80,AND([@Wages]>=9001,[@Wages]<=11999),150,[@Wages]>=12000,200)
```

But am stuck on how to check where maximum duties performed by the person and use formula accordingly.

Am using Office 365 (monthly targeted channel) so all the dynamic functions are available with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `FILTER` function, you can use:

```
=IF([@Wages]=MAX(FILTER([Wages],[name]=[@name])),VLOOKUP(SUM(FILTER([Wages],[name]=[@name])),{0,0;6000,80;9001,150;12000,200},2),"")
```

[image]

Note that I used `VLOOKUP` instead of `IFS` since I then only had to add up the wages once.

**EDIT:**

To account for the additional requirement mentioned in the comments of only showing the result in the first of any matching highest wages row, we merely have to add a criteria to see if we have met that specification in above rows.

- I use `COUNTIFS` to do that, and only checking the current row and the rows above.

  - Note the structure used to do this in a Table
- Also, to show another approach, I also used `MAXIFS` rather than `MAX(FILTER(…` to calculate the maximum wage in the `COUNTIFS` formula.

  - *I don't know whether one or the other is more efficient*
  - *You could also replace `SUM(FILTER(…` in a similar way with `SUMIFS`, if you wanted to (or if you were using a version of Excel that did not have the `FILTER` function).

```
=IF(
     AND(
          COUNTIFS(INDEX([name],1,1):[@name],[@name],INDEX([Wages],1,1):[@Wages],MAXIFS([Wages],[name],[@name]))=1,
          [@Wages]=MAXIFS([Wages],[name],[@name])),
     VLOOKUP(SUM(FILTER([Wages],[name]=[@name])),{0,0;6000,80;9001,150;12000,200},2),
"")
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine, only issue is if wages are same for repeated name then it shows PT amount for both the entries. How to overcome this. Also a question, why vlookup, I heard xlookup is far better than vlookup. And yes, i have all the latest dynamic array functions available with me. Thanks

Comment: If wages are same for a person then there should be only one PT amount, i.e. the 1st occurence.

Comment: @Rahul See my edit for your additional request of only showing a result next to the first row of repeats.  With regard to `XLOOKUP`, what feature of this function do you think would be ***far better*** than `VLOOKUP` **when used in this formula**?  Of course, there are differences, but I'm not sure what you mean by ***far better*** here. (or even a little bit better)

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Regarding xlookup vs vlookup, I am not that geek to understand the overall difference between these 2 formulas, I just heard via few videos on youtube regarding this new xlookup function which is (claimed) better than vlookup. but if you have used vlookup then there must be some good reason, its good to go. Am very much thankful to you.

Comment: @Rahul There are instances when `XLOOKUP` is preferable, but here we are dealing with a small 2D array constant consisting of the equivalent of two columns and multiple rows. `XLOOKUP` is particularly useful (and preferable) when the lookup column is not just to the left of the result column; and especially is the arrays are quite large. It's also a newer function.